# How to find if a Rails Resources key has a value within it's array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails resource Documents.
These documents have an property called `author_ids` which is an array of `user_id`'s.

Example:

```
@document.author_ids = [1,2,3,4]
```

I'm building a dashboard that displays all the Documents.

```
def dashboard
 @documents = Documents.all
end
```

I would like all users within the author_ids to view the documents.
I want to do something like below, where I search to see if the value of the current_user.id is included in the array of author_ids on the Documents resource and list those Documents as @documents.

```
def dashboard
 @documents = Document.all.where(:author_ids.include?(current_user.id))
end
```

I know I cannot call .include? on the Key (:author_ids) which is an array. I need Help iterating over each value in the key :author_id to check if the value of the current_user.id is within the :author_id array.

Comment: what do you mean by `property`? is it an attribute/column in Document or a method in model?

Comment: yea attribute like @document.author_ids => [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must have

```
class Document
  has_many :document_authors
  has_many :authors, through: :document_authors
```

then this will return you the expected result

```
def dashboard
  @documents = Document.joins(:authors).where(authors: { id: current_user.id})
end
```

Comment: This sounds like it would work but theres an issue. I don't know the authors_ids at all. Basically I send this document by email. 
When I press the send button I call create_authors() which is a method that
searches my Users resource to see if the email i'm sending the document to is exists in the database. If not I create a new user and add the user_id onto the  document.author_ids array and update the document. If so I push that author_id onto the array as well and update the document. Instead of creating another model, I'd rather just push a value into an array.